# MySql workbench query history ( last executed query / queries ) i.e. create / alter table, select, insert update queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, history

Want to see last executed queries in MySql Workbench whether its

> create / alter table query
>
> select / insert / update query
> or any query list.

in short want to see history of all queries

Comment: on Terminal (Linux) ? or by an SQL query ?

Comment: @Begueradj in IDE got it. below ans is correct.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

From the bottom panel, change "Action Output" to "History" and then choose the appropriate date.

Alternatively, the SQL statement history is stored in text files under two locations:

- *sql_history/yyyy-mm-dd* e.g., sql_history/2015-04-01: Full Workbench SQL history for all MySQL connections
- *log/sql_actions_*.log*: SQL history execution results, but without the data, and separated per MySQL connection

The location of these files depends on your system. For additional details, see 
[MySQL Workbench Settings and Log Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-configuring-files.html)

In both cases, you will see the query history.

[image]

Comment: For some reason, my history is being added to the wrong date even though DATETIME of the server is correct.

Comment: is it possible to see result data from these queries  ?

Comment: for the latest version it is only showing "history output" no option as "history" and in the history output not all query which were exceuted are shown is there any other way

Answer (score 17):

C:\Users[WinUser]\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\sql_history

you find a log file for each day. It includes manual and automated queries from workbench (e.g. UPDATES via edit in Table)

Answer (score 14):

Suppose that you can no longer connect to a previous MySQL database instance, and you just want to see your SQL history from the editors. Do this:

1. Locate your MySQLWorkbench [settings folder](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-configuring-files.html):

- **Windows:** `%AppData%\MySQL\Workbench\` -- which is usually `C:\Users\your_username\AppData\MySQL\Workbench\` (Note that the AppData folder is hidden by default, so you may want to [unhide AppData](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/appdata-where-to-find-the-appdata-folder-in-windows-10/) first, to see its contents.)
- **macOS:** `/Users/your_username/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench/` (Note that the ~/Library folder is hidden by default, so you may want to [unhide it](https://www.howtogeek.com/273430/how-to-access-the-hidden-library-folder-on-your-mac/) first, to see the contents)
- **Linux:** `/Users/your_username/.mysql/workbench/`

2. Open the folder **`sql_workspaces`** (inside `Workbench`)
3. You should see folders of your previous database connections. Navigate into one of them.
4. There should be several **`"*.scratch"` files**. They are text files of **editor history of SQL queries.**
5. Open these `*.scratch` files in a text editor, and copy the contents.

Answer (score 8):

You will find a complete History file in:

C:\Users\[WinUser]\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\log\sql_actions_unconnected.txt

MySQL Workbench could not open History file for some reason, but I was able to recover my unsaved queries by browsing this history file.

Answer (score 0):

History of queries executed can be found by 2 ways mentioned in the following answer:

1. Recovering from **MYSQL Workbench HISTORY**
2. Recovering from **AUTOSAVE file**

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464375/7397820