# MySQL workbench workspace restore

Tags: mysql, workbench

EVerytime i open my sql workbench, it never restores my workspace ,I always get an error

> could not read contents  of C/USer...

How can i make this stop?

Comment: that only happens, when it was not closed correctly

Comment: which os are you using ???

Comment: I use Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this in the future, close the workbench then delete all data and directories here:

```
    C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\sql_workspaces
```

Answer (score 0):

While the workspace auto restore might not be possible, following are the options to restore your executed queries in MySQL Workbench:

1. **Recovering from **HISTORY****
2. **Recovering from **AUTO SAVE****

***1 -> HISTORY***

All the query execution history of each day is maintained in by the workbench:

Extra details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26618099/7397820
[image]

**2 -> Recovering from AUTOSAVE**

```
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\log\sql_actions_unconnected.log
```

You can find the list of all executed queries in past and their results in `sql_actions_unconnected.log`

Example:

[image]

***IMPORTANT NOTE!:** Don't forget to remove the contents of the following directory:

> `C:\Users\{{USERNAME*\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\sql_workspaces`

Deleting this will only help to avoid problems in future not restore the existing workspace according to
https://superuser.com/questions/981333/mysql-workbench-unable-to-restore-workspace/1007793#1007793