# How to improve this MySQL Query using join?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have got a simple query and it takes more than 14 seconds.

```
select 
     e.title, e.date, v.name, v.city, v.region, v.country

from seminar e force index for join (venueid) 
     left join venues v on e.venueid = v.id 

where v.country = 'US'
     and v.city = 'New York' 
     and v.region = 'NY'
     and e.date > curdate() 
     and e.someid != 0
```

*Note: count(e.id) stands for an abbreviation for debugging purposes. In fact we get information from both tables.*

Explain gives this:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-----------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type        | possible_keys                                                                        | key                      | key_len | ref             | rows | Extra                                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-----------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | v     | index_merge | PRIMARY,city,country,region | city,region | 378,378 | NULL            |    2 | Using intersect(city,region); Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | ref         | venueid                     |  venueid    | 5       | v.id            |   11 | Using where                                            |
+----+-------------+-------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-----------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have indexes on e.id, e.date, e.someid, as well as v.id, v.country, v.city and v.region.

I know the db-setup is a mess but that's what I have to deal with right now.

Why does the SQL take so long as in the end there will be an approx. count 150? In events there are about 1M entries and in venues about 100K.

Both tables are MyISAM. Any ideas how to improve this?

Upon creating an index like this

```
create index location on venues (city, region, country)
```

it takes 20 seconds, the explain is this:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------------+------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                        | key          | key_len | ref               | rows | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------------+------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | v     | ref  | PRIMARY,city,country,region,location | location     | 765     | const,const,const |  410 | Using index condition; Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | ref  | EventVenueID                         | venueid      | 5       | v.id              |   11 | Using where                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------------+------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Do you want the number of events that have a venue in Vancouver?

Comment: Actually I want information from the tables, the count is just an abbreviation to get the output limited when I try to optimize the query.

Comment: Then you should edit your query to show a couple of columns - it changes the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went another way since it seems that MySQL can't handle joins effectively:

- Created one big new table with all the columns I need from the join
- So the seminars and events are in one table now
- added indexes

Now the query is fast. Don't know why...

#### From 25 seconds, we are down to .08 seconds

That's how I wanted it.

If anybody still knows why, you are more than welcome to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have `left join venues`, but you have conditions in the `where` clause on the joined `venues` row, so only joined rows will be returned. However, that's a side issue - read on for why you don't need a join at all.

Next, if the city is `vancouver`, there's no need to *also* test for country or state.

Finally, if you're trying to find "how many future events are in Vancouver", you don't need a join, as the venue id is a constant!

Try this:

```
select count(*) as event_count
from events
where venueid = (select id from venues where city = 'vancouver')
and startdate > curdate() 
and te_id != 0
```

Mysql will use the index on `venueid` without you having to use a hint. If it doesn't, execute this:

```
analyze events
```

which will update the statistics of the data distribution in the indexed columns. Note that if a lot of your events are in Vancouver, it's more efficient to *not* use an index (as most of the rows will have to be accessed anyway).

Comment: Nice Idea, won't work here because I need information on both tables. I used count here to get a minimum sql in reality I get some columns. City... is not static but is determined by the code here on the backend, it could be others... or a vancouver in the US.

Answer (score 0):

This would make the first part of the query faster:

```
INDEX(city, region, country)
```

Comment: Interesting, now it takes 20 seconds. mybe I understood you wrong, can you provide a full statement? i used create index location on venues (city, region, country)

Comment: What's the `EXPLAIN?  Was the cache warm?

Comment: I updated the question. What do you mean by cache warm?

Comment: Hmmm... This is puzzling.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables; I need to see the indexes.

Comment: The first time you run a query, the cache might be cold, and the query has to fetch data from disk.  The second time, the cache is warm, and the query (often) runs ten times as fast.  If the second query takes <2ms, the "Query cache" may have kicked in; this reading is bogus.

Comment: Are ther about 410 rows in `venues` for "vancouver"?  (This seems 'wrong'.)

Comment: The first time it takes long, then it's fast. I empty the cache on purpose to see how i can improve the query. Users look for events in different locations and therefor the where is different. Then the query will mostly run slow for those scenarios. Do you have an alternative solution to this?

Comment: I use this technique for getting a measure of 'cost' of a query:  `FLUSH STATUS; SELECT ...; SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`.  Bigger numbers = bigger 'cost'.  Often there are numbers that look like number of rows in a table -- this probably indicates a table scan.  "Writes" (in a `SELECT`) indicates a tmp table.  Etc.

Comment: How do you "empty the cache"?  By restarting mysqld?  Even if your cache is not big enough, this is overkill because it flushes out top level blocks in BTrees, leading to unrealistically high timings.  If, on the other hand, you mean the "Query cache", then simply do `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` when testing.

Comment: I use RamMap from Sysinternals and empty the Standby-List. The system is running on a Windows Machine.

Comment: If you are using `Engine=MyISAM`, that (I guess) destroys only the "data" blocks; index blocks are cached in the "key_buffer".  If you are using `Engine=InnoDB`, that (I guess) does nothing to MySQL.  Don't use it; it only confuses the issue.

Comment: Both tables are MyISAM.