# Where should I focus: Optimize the query, changing database config or what else?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I took over a project and have 2 MyISAM tables.

- table1 with approx. 1M rows, and
- table2 with approx. 100K rows.

In the project these tables are accessed often, and at first it seems ok.

After I installed the project on a Windows 8.1 for local development I found that every day, the first time I access the site, my **query takes 14 seconds.** A bit too much.

**Afterwards is less than 0.1 second.**

Now, since on dev this accumulated with another query runs into a timeout-exception for php, it got me concerned about whether it's recommended to do anything about it or not. On production it seems not to occur (or hard to reproduce).

I heard of things like warm cache or optimize query but don't know what is meant by that.

**What do experts like you do in this case?**

I had another question set up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150650) trying to see whether I can optimize the query.

Changing to InnoDB doesn't seem to have an impact.

Comment: Hard to give any advice without understanding both the table schema and the queries you are running as a starting point.

Comment: How are they accessed? Are they both accessed simultaneously at the first run? The 14 seconds includes accessing both tables?

Comment: @Mike: I edited the question. I rather wanted to know how to generally approach this topic. Whether I should focus on the query or adjusting the database config or what else there is. I never saw that behavior before, maybe that's normal for big tables.

Comment: @hogan  There are a number of potential problems.  Maybe your table schema is not exposing indexes appropriate to your query, maybe your query is not written correctly to leverage indexes, maybe your MySQL configuration does not have appropriate amount of memory allocated to store indexes in memory, etc.  The best place to start though is with the table schema and examples of query(ies) in question.

Comment: This issue appears to require complete analysis (db settings, architecture and sql optimization). Maybe the solution is simple, but as Mike said there's not much that can be done intelligently without having access to the server. Let me know if you want an invoice for this. (I don't know if SO is the proper place for this kind of comment?)

Comment: The best optimization for you at this point would be converting this to InnoDB and forgetting MyISAM ever existed. Then tuning the value of magical variable `innodb_buffer_pool_size` will open a door to inexplicable, yet amazing performance that will blow you away.

Comment: @N.B. It was MyISAM and before I let it be that way because once a day, there is data written, all other times it is reading. So I thought this is the way to go. Despite that I changed to InnoDB yesterday and now the initial query is twice as slow. about 30 seconds. Do you know any reason for this? And is 7 seconds a 'normal' time for that size of tables?

Answer (score 0):

The "first" time you run a query, two things may or may not happen:

- Lots of disk I/O *may* be done to fetch the index blocks and/or data blocks from disk.  (If other queries happened to have fetched those blocks, the blocks may be cached already.)  (14s vs 0.1s is more than I usually see for this cold/warm cache difference.)
- If the "Query cache" was on, the first `SELECT` and its resultset were stored in the QC.  The second call *may* have found it there and returned the result almost instantly.  (Usually this is ~1ms, not the 100ms you mentioned.)  The QC can be bypassed for a single query by saying `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`.

Since it is annoying you daily, you may as well go through the exercise of trying to optimize the query.  If the tables are growing daily, it may get slower and slower over time.  Note that if production needs to be restarted for any reason, that query may timeout on it.  So, *yes*, try to optimize it.

A million rows is beginning to be "big".

The characteristics of this indicate that you are I/O-bound only initially.  So it does not indicate that key_buffer_size and innodb_buffer_pool_size are too low.

If you want to discuss the performance of a particular query, start a new thread and provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: He's using MyISAM. Buffer pool has no power over it, sadly :/

Comment: I'm usually careful to be Engine-agnostic in my answers; I think my answer stands.  (He should change to InnoDB, but it would be coincidental if it made any difference.)

Comment: I think you're more than qualified to know that swapping to InnoDB with the proper buffer pool size will make a huge impact :) we're talking about reading from RAM (which is what, some 30-40 GB/s these days) vs crappy mechanical drive that reaches maybe 60 MB/s on a good day, with the whole load of issues with seeks and what not. I won't even mention IOPS difference.

Comment: I would guess that the majority of MySQL installations are still on spinning platters.  The OP's 14sec. _seemed_ to imply a slooow disk.